# Leave/dismiss textfield on button action

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

Im doing a login field. It consists of UITextfields and a button that pops up a picker controller. When the button is clicked on to show the button pop I want to remove/leave/dismiss editing the textfield.

I tried:

[sender resignFirstResponder];

But it doesnt work.

What I'm aiming for is to leave the textfield editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is sender here?

Make a `IBOutLet` of your `UITextField` and Try this

```
[yourTextFieldName resignFirstResponder];
```

Or if you don't want to make `IBOutlet` then try this.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Or you can set delegate to your textfield and then

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, sorry it was such a silly mistake, how did I miss that. I will mark it as correct answer when the time allows.

Comment: Stack overflow prevents you from accepting an answer within 10mins haha

Answer (score 0):

I set the delegate of the UITextField to my ViewController class. In that class I implimented this method

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return NO;
  }

Answer (score 0):

put this code,in button action method

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

inside     viewDidLoad

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *myLabel1Tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap)];
        [myLabel1Tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:myLabel1Tap];
```

then type

```
-(void)oneTap
{
    [yourTextFieldName  resignFirstResponder];
}
```